How to use REST API to delete message on Azure Storage Queue in bash?
I would like to know how to delete a message on Azure Storage Queue. Currently I keep getting the following error.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:47de86b5-3003-004d-0fc0-dd56e6000000
Time:2024-07-24T11:56:26.1466778Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '<signature>' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'DELETE











x-ms-date:Wed, 24 Jul 2024 11:56:25 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
/gildedhonordev/ghmatchedtickets/messages/<messageid>'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Using this page as guidance, I have created a function that successfully get the queued message. However, the same method keeps failing at the Authorization when I want to delete a message.
Below are my codes:
get_queued_message() {
    DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    VERSION="2016-05-31"
    HEADER_RESOURCE="x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO\nx-ms-version:$VERSION"
    URL_RESOURCE="/$STORAGE_ACC/$QUEUE_NAME/messages"
    STRING_TO_SIGN="GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$HEADER_RESOURCE\n$URL_RESOURCE"

    DECODED_KEY="$(echo -n "$STORAGE_KEY" | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"
    SIGN=$(printf "$STRING_TO_SIGN" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$DECODED_KEY" -binary | base64 -w0)
    
    RET=$(curl -X GET \
        -H "x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO" \
        -H "x-ms-version:$VERSION" \
        -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STORAGE_ACC:$SIGN" \
        -H "Content-Length:0" \
        "https://$STORAGE_ACC.queue.core.windows.net/$QUEUE_NAME/messages")

    MESSAGE=$(echo "$RET" | grep -oP '<MessageText>\K[^<]+')
    MESSAGE_ID=$(echo "$RET" | grep -oP '<MessageId>\K[^<]+')
    POP_RECEIPT=$(echo "$RET" | grep -oP '<PopReceipt>\K[^<]+')
}

delete_queued_message() {
    DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    VERSION="2016-05-31"
    HEADER_RESOURCE="x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO\nx-ms-version:$VERSION"
    URL_RESOURCE="/$STORAGE_ACC/$QUEUE_NAME/messages/$MESSAGE_ID?popreceipt=$POP_RECEIPT"
    STRING_TO_SIGN="DELETE\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$HEADER_RESOURCE\n$URL_RESOURCE"

    DECODED_KEY="$(echo -n "$STORAGE_KEY" | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"
    SIGN=$(printf "$STRING_TO_SIGN" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$DECODED_KEY" -binary | base64 -w0)

    curl -X DELETE \
        -H "x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO" \
        -H "x-ms-version:$VERSION" \
        -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STORAGE_ACC:$SIGN" \
        "https://$STORAGE_ACC.queue.core.windows.net/$QUEUE_NAME/messages/$MESSAGE_ID?popreceipt=$POP_RECEIPT"
}

Any help would be appreciated


How to use REST API to delete message on Azure Storage Queue in bash?

You can use the below script to Delete Azure Storage Queue message using Bash.
Script:
#!/bin/bash

# Function to convert base64 to hex
base64_to_hex() {
    echo -n "$1" | base64 --decode | od -An -tx1 | tr -d ' \n'
}

# Function to delete the queued message
delete_queued_message() {
    STORAGE_ACC=$1
    STORAGE_KEY=$2
    QUEUE_NAME=$3
    MESSAGE_ID=$4
    POP_RECEIPT=$5

    DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    VERSION="2020-04-08"
    HEADER_RESOURCE="x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO\nx-ms-version:$VERSION"
    CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE="/$STORAGE_ACC/$QUEUE_NAME/messages/$MESSAGE_ID\npopreceipt:$POP_RECEIPT"
    STRING_TO_SIGN="DELETE\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$HEADER_RESOURCE\n$CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE"

    DECODED_KEY=$(base64_to_hex "$STORAGE_KEY")
    SIGN=$(printf "$STRING_TO_SIGN" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$DECODED_KEY" -binary | base64)

    curl -X DELETE \
        -H "x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO" \
        -H "x-ms-version:$VERSION" \
        -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STORAGE_ACC:$SIGN" \
        "https://$STORAGE_ACC.queue.core.windows.net/$QUEUE_NAME/messages/$MESSAGE_ID?popreceipt=$POP_RECEIPT"
}


STORAGE_ACC="venkat326123"
STORAGE_KEY="T3czZpu1gZzzzzzzztD9nyWw=="
QUEUE_NAME="queue1"
MESSAGE_ID="aeacazzzzzf6914a"
POP_RECEIPT="AgAzzzAAAA09p8nc3d2gE="


delete_queued_message $STORAGE_ACC $STORAGE_KEY $QUEUE_NAME $MESSAGE_ID $POP_RECEIPT

The above script executed and deleted azure storage queue message in my environment.
Portal:

Reference:
Delete Message (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

It is ok to give ready code but without explanation and several bad practices, it has room for improvements as an answer. Some of the problems in this code: Do not use all capital variables unless those are global environment variables. Always double quote variable expansions. Do not use echo -n but portable printf %s, do not use variables in printf's format strings. Format string should always be a literal. Example: base64_to_hex() { printf %s "$1" | base64 -d | od -tx1 -An | tr -d '[:space:]';}

DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z") you also need LC_TIME=C or the output will use the localized names.

Storing API credentials in a shell script is very insecure and a common cause of data leak.

Thanks for information :) @LéaGris since op used in capital variable so I explained in capital letter.

Will keep in my mind for future queries and once again thanks for info.. @LéaGris
